# send email from laravel using gmail smpt/sendgrid

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, sendgrid

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', '465'),
'from' => [
        'address' => 'my_gmail',
        'name' => 'OnlineKina',
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'my_user'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'my_secret'),
```

but i am getting this type of error :

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net
> :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
> ssl://smtp.sendgrid.net:465 (Connection refused)
>
> while used gmail smtp : Connection could not be established with host
> smtp.gmail.com:stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
> ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465(Network unreachable)

if i used mail driver as smtp then it throws error but if i used sendmail as driver then mail comes/goes in spam folder

Comment: Did you check with [tag:MailTrap]??

Comment: no but i have checked with sendgrid

Comment: I think 465 is blocked from your server

Comment: i have discussed with hosting provider they says there is no any port blocked from server

Comment: Check with https://MailTrap.Io

Comment: i am getting this error while using mailtrap : Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (Connection refused)

Comment: Have you setup your mail user name and password correctly?

Comment: yes i have used user_name, password given by mailtrap

Answer (score 0):

in the `.env` file change the driver to `sendmail`
if Gmail has 2fa make sure you create an app password and use that password instead of your Gmail password in the `.env` file.

Cheers

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=***********
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL/TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=a*****************
MAIL_FROM_NAME="***************"
```